# Check if previous post in the same category

Tags: php, wordpress

I need something like this:

```
if (previous_post_is_the_same_category()){
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: We are going to need way more context and code than this to be able to help I'm afraid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function already in Wordpress to get the previous post 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post

You can pass a boolean of true as the first parameter to return the previous post which is in the same category, you can then compare the post IDs to see if the previous post is also the previous post in the same category. Something like this...

```
$previousPost = get_previous_post();
$previousPostInSameCat = get_previous_post(true);
if($previousPost->ID === $previousPostInSameCat->ID){
    ...
}else{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It was to simple. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

That is very vague. You could have a variable that changes according to the category. Guessing you are pulling all your articles (or whatever) from a while f.ex;

```
$category = NULL;
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    if($result['category'] == $category) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }

    $category = $result['category'];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that this is in Wordpress.  I know there is <?php get_previous_post( $in_same_cat, $excluded_categories ) ?> but I can't use it if I want to check previous post category.

Comment: *"Sorry, I didn't mention that this is in Wordpress"* - @KubaModrzejewski You didn't need to, since you used the [`wordpress`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) tag for the question.

Comment: @ Fred-ii- you are very right. I apologize - didn't notice.

Comment: @Jeppesen no worries ;-) *cheers* - Your answer may serve someone else later on.